# Compass.trueHeading instead of pointing at north points at the current direction my android device is pointing

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I made a UI compass for android in which I want the north needle to point at north direction all the time but it points at the direction my android device is pointing at.

For Example if my android device is pointing at west, the needle will point at west. I am using `Compass.TrueHeading`, according to unity docs it should point at geographical north. Any help will be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Compass : MonoBehaviour
{
//target is the Compass needle
public Transform target;
private float north;
private void Start()
{
   Input.compass.enabled = true;
   Input.location.Start();
 }  
void Update()
{
  north = -Input.compass.trueHeading;
  CompassRotate();
}
public void CompassRotate()
{
  target.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(target.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 
  0, north), Time.deltaTime * 2);
}
```

**Note** : I expect the needle to point at geographical north whatever the orientation of my device is.

Comment: Try removing the Slerp and just setting the rotation to the target value each frame. It won't look as nice, but it helps isolate the problem. Also try using Magnetic North to see if that reports what you expect.

Comment: @Draco18s It displays same result with both trueHeading and magneticHeading and by removing Slerp the needle shows jerky movement but still doesnt points at north.

Comment: I remember I had some issues getting things to work the first time too, but my working code is effectively identical to your broken code, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @Draco18s Are you able to detect actual direction? If yes can you please share your code here.

Comment: Yes, I can. I used `compassObj.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, heading);` where heading was assigned the value of `Input.compass.magneticHeading` and compassObj is a canvas Image. For smoothing I used DOTween and only if the new heading and the previous heading were different.

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks! it is working now with both trueHeading and magneticHeading. The problem was with negative sign,                                          ( - Input.compass.trueHeading). With the negative sign the needle points at the current direction and without the negative sign it points at the geographical north.